# Can not realize thymleaf logic with image

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have following expression:

```
<img th:src="@{/api/file/{imageName}(imageName = ${account.profileImageLink})}" alt="profile picture">
```

and I want to realize next logic:
if imageName equals null so imageName = "profile.jpg"

how can I do that through Thymleaf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of different ways to accomplish this.

1. The [elvis operator](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#default-expressions-elvis-operator):

   ```
   <img th:src="@{/api/file/{imageName}(imageName=${account.profileImageLink} ?: 'profile.jpg')}" alt="profile picture">
   ```
2. Conditionals.

   ```
   <img th:if="${account.profileImageLink != null}" th:src="@{/api/file/{imageName}(imageName = ${account.profileImageLink})}" alt="profile picture">
   <img th:unless="${account.profileImageLink != null}" th:src="@{/api/file/profile.jpg}" alt="profile picture">
   ```
3. th:with / ternary:

   ```
   <img th:with="image=${account.profileImageLink == null ? 'profile.jpg' : account.profileImageLink}"
        th:src="@{/api/file/{imageName}(imageName=${image})}" alt="profile picture">
   ```